# Need help with a custom Spinner/ArrayAdapter setup

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

**EDIT:** Please ignore this question - I've managed to solve it in a way which works fine for what I need (see my own answer below).

I have a WeatherSpinner class which extends Spinner. The class shows region names which I originally did using an `ArrayAdapter<String>` but I now want to use `ArrayAdapter<Locale>`(Locale is an abstract 'empty' class of my own).

I'm getting a `ClassCastException` when trying to populate my ArrayAdapter with the following...

```
protected ArrayList<?> theList;
protected ArrayAdapter<Locale> aa = null;
...
protected void updateContents(ArrayList<?> list, int selectedItem) {
    theList = list;
    // Exception thrown on next line
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<Locale>(theContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        (Locale[]) theList.toArray());
    ...
```

}

I'm passing a `RegionList` object into updateContents() as the 'list' parameter and `RegionList extends ArrayList<Region>`, and `Region extends Locale`. I've also overriden Region's `toString()` method to return a valid String.

What am I not seeing here? Am I wrong about the way `ArrayList<?>.toArray()` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved.

I needed to use the toArray(T[] contents) method of ArrayList as follows...

```
Locale[] locArray = new Locale[theList.size()];
locArray = (Locale[]) theList.toArray(locArray);
aa = new ArrayAdapter<Locale>(theContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        locArray);
```